# recursively solve equation and saving the values

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica. I am trying to recursively solve an equation and saving the values into a `Table`. Since I need the real solutions only I use `Reduce`.

The following is my code:

```
f = 5.68672 T + 6.46776 T^3

t = Table[i, {i, 0.2, 3, 0.2}]

sols = Table[Reduce[f == t[[i]], T, Reals], {i, Length[t]}]
{T == 0.0351204, T == 0.06995, T == 0.104221, T == 0.137708, 
 T == 0.170237, T == 0.201687, T == 0.231988, T == 0.26111, 
 T == 0.289058, T == 0.315857, T == 0.34155, T == 0.366188, 
 T == 0.389828, T == 0.412529, T == 0.434347}
```

The solution is OK as I compared it to other software as well. The only thing that matters me is how to remove the T== , i.e. I just need the solution and then to copy this into another table, say sols2 that contains

```
sols2 = {0.0351204, 0.06995, 0.104221, T == 0.137708,.., 0.434347}
```

I tried the following: `sols2 = T/.sols` but get the following error:

> ```
> sols2 = ReplaceAll::reps: ... is neither a list of replacement rules nor 
>    a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
> ```

Does anyone know how to remove the T==?

Comment: What equation are you actually trying to solve? I don't see one.

Answer (score 3):

You get

```
  {0.0351204, 0.06995, 0.104221, 0.137709, 0.170237, 0.201687, 0.231988, 0.26111, 0.289058, 0.315857, 0.34155, 0.366188, 0.389828, 0.412529, 0.434347}
```

using any of the methods below:

```
   Last /@ sols
```

or

```
   sols[[All,2]]
```

or

```
  sols /. (a_ == b_) -> b
```

All give a list of solutions with `T==` removed.

**Update:** an alternative approach to get a list of solutions for `T` is to `Map` `Reduce[...]` on the list `t`:

```
  solutionlist = Map[Reduce[f == #, T, Reals][[2]] &, t]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Wayan, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

After your Reduce you can do something as:

```
T /. (sols /. a_Equal :> {Rule @@ a})

{0.0351204, 0.06995, 0.104221, 0.137709, 0.170237, 0.201687, \
0.231988, 0.26111, 0.289058, 0.315857, 0.34155, 0.366188, 0.389828, \
0.412529, 0.434347}
```

Answer (score 3):

`T == 0.0351204` has the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html): `Equal[T, 0.0351204]` and you want the second argument of the function `Equal`, therefore you could use:

```
sols /. Equal -> (#2 &)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRules.html) and then make the replacement you attempted:

```
T /. ToRules /@ sols
```

---

As a side matter, there is a cleaner syntax for your second `Table` application:

```
Table[Reduce[f == i, T, Reals], {i, t}]
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in Mma8 you can pass `Reals` to `Solve` or `NDSolve` and then proceed like you tried:

```
sols = Table[First@NSolve[f == t[[i]], T, Reals], {i, Length[t]}]
T/.sols
```

Comment: Hi Peter,

I copy and paste your code but the following error arise:
T /. sols
ReplaceAll::reps: {T==0.0351204,T==0.06995,T==0.104221,T==0.137709,T==0.170237,T==0.201687,<<3>>,T==0.315857,T==0.34155,T==0.366188,T==0.389828,T==0.412529,T==0.434347} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

T /. {T == 0.0351204, T == 0.06995, T == 0.104221, T == 0.137709, 
  T == 0.170237, T == 0.201687, T == 0.231988, T == 0.26111, 
  T == 0.289058, T == 0.315857, T == 0.34155, T == 0.366188, 
  T == 0.389828, T == 0.412529, T == 0.434347}

Comment: @Wayan It seems, you took `Reduce` instead of `Solve` or `NSolve` because I see "==" signs in your output.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I just realized there was a typo. I works now. Thanks Peter!